# JNI: Call C# method from Java

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface, native

I want to call C# method from Java using JNI.  I have the DLL as well as the exe  with me. Hello world program in C# looks like:

```
using Test;


    {
            clsMain tst = new clsMain;
            clsInput input = new clsInput;
            clsOutput output = new clsOutput;
            input.strTekstInput = "John";
            output = tst.funMain(input);
            MsgBox(output.strTekstOutput);
        }
```

I want to call this method and print the output using JNI. But I am not sure how to achieve this as I have never used JNI. Can someone help with What I need to do here? Appreciate response.

regards,
Venky

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't JNI for native? C# isn't native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you cannot directly call the C# method from Java code but you can write C++ wrapper. This C++ wrapper can be get called from Java code and eventually this C++ wrapper can call C# method.

So it would be like this: Java --> C++ Wrapper --> C#

Comment: There's probabaly much more to it because that C# function must run on a CLR (.NET runtime) - who runs this CLR?

Comment: Thanks Prashant.  It is indeed very difficult to achieve this specially because we are only allowed to use Linux only.